# How to specify what sharedPreferences to automatically backup?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

`Auto Backup for Apps automatically backs up a user's data from apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later.`

I've a specific SharedPreferences data that I want to automatically back-up, but not all SharedPreferences. Is that possible to do?

Problem: I save an information about user on how much times he has opened application. I'd love to save this number on cloud, because, alot of users nowadays go to Google Play Store and update an existing application following (Uninstall -> Install). Well, as for now, my `allowBackup=false`, which means, that whenever user uninstalls app, the crucial information about user and his application opening count is lost. If I set `allowBackup=true` then I keep saving unnesassary data. Is there a possibility to save on the cloud part of SharedPreferences (not everything)? Is there other alternatives?

Comment: you can't customize which preferences to save. You may want to use other ways to save your info instead. Firebase for example

Comment: you can implement a custom backup mechanism. This is explained in the docs

Comment: @TimCastelijns Can u expand on that, preferably giving small example?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles